# Serial port acquisition thread gets slow when focused Qwidget in Qt

Tags: multithreading, focus, delay, qwidget, acquisition

I have a problem with signal acquisition. I have a class called rawdataprovider that is responsible for acquiring data from the serial port. This class is in a thread with the highest priority, and every 25 ms it extracts the data from serial port, through the QExtSerialPort class. While only that is done, the program works correctly, that is, every 25ms the data is extracted from the serial port and sent to the class in charge of managing them. The problem starts when I navigate through the interface, particularly when I move through the Qwidget of the main interface. The processing associated with focusing a Qwidget and painting a frame on it, makes the signal that should be sent every 25 ms to extract the data from the serial port be delayed. Any ideas to solve this problem?

I find it difficult to understand that the simple fact of focusing a Qwidget delays so much a thread. I have tried other ways to extract data from the serial port. I tried to connect the readyRead () signal, which is sent when there is data available on the serial port, with the method responsible for processing the data, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: Pretty easy to create a firehose bug in a case like this.  If you get a sample every 25 msec but it takes more than 25 msec to update the UI then you will always fall behind.  Worse and worse over time.  Focus on providing useful data to the user's eyes, they are far slower than 25 msec.  A thread-safe queue that you don't empty more than 10 times a second and don't allow to grow too big, dropping or merging data if necessary, something like that.

Comment: I confess that I don’t know what a firehose bug is. If you can be more specific, I would appreciate it. I understand when you say that it’s logical that the acquisition of the signal is delayed when the UI is updated, and I have to agree because that is what is happening to me.

Comment: But I don’t understand how a thread-safe queue can be useful here. The problem isn’t that i'm losing data. The problem is that every 25 ms I need the data of the signal sent by serial port to paint it in a real-time system. It’s that updating the UI makes the acquisition so slow that the representation of it does not look like it was in real time. I don't do anything with a thread-safe queue that accumulates and processes the data.